# How can I get time for each name

Tags: java, arrays

**  it show me the same time   23,May 1986     Output  ...Person 0: John Davidson, 23 , May 1986, Belgrade;
Person 1: Michael Barton, 23 , May 1986, Krakov;
Person 2: Ivan Perkinson, 23 , May 1986, Moscow;**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Persons {
    public String name;
  public String lastName;
   public String Birthplace;
   public static  String dateBirth;
     Persons(String name, String lastName, String Birthplace, String dateBirth) {
            this.name = name;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.Birthplace = Birthplace;
            Persons.dateBirth = dateBirth;
    }
    public String getName() {
          return name;
   }

    public String getLastName() {
           return lastName;
    }
  public String getPlace() {
            return Birthplace;
  }
    public String getDateBirth() {
            return dateBirth;
  }

   public void setDateBirth(String dateBirth) {
     Persons.dateBirth = dateBirth;
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd ',' MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
  SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
      List<Persons> details = new ArrayList<Persons>();
      String text = "John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
      String[] personsSplit = text.split(" ");
      for (int i = 0; i < personsSplit.length; i++) {
      String[]  personList = personsSplit[i].split("/");
      String[] print = personList[0].split("\\.");
      Persons newPerson = new Persons(print[0], print[1],
      personList[2],  personList[1]);
      details .add(newPerson);
           }
          for (int i = 0; i <details .size(); i++) {
                   String outputString = "Person " + i + ": "
                                    + details .get(i).getName() + " "
                                    + details .get(i).getLastName() + ", "
                                    +formatter.format(parser.parse(dateBirth)) + ", "
                                    + details .get(i).getPlace() + ";";
                    System.out.println(outputString);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not  `this.dateBirth = dateBirth;`?

Comment: You have not explained at all your question.

Comment: @UmaKanth because dateBirth is a static property for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `dateBirth` is static. This means that whenever it is changed on one person, it is changed on all of the other people as well. The last person has a date of birth of May 23, 1968, so, since it is the last time the variable is changed, that is what all of the People have as their date of birth.

Fix:

1. Remove `static` from `public static String dateBirth`.
2. Change all instances of `Person.dateBirth` to `this.dateBirth`.
3. To fix the error, `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field dateBirth`, change the `dateBirth` in you `main` method to `details.get(i).getDateBirth()`.

Your final code should be:

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Persons {
    public String name;
    public String lastName;
    public String Birthplace;
    public String dateBirth;
    Persons(String name, String lastName, String Birthplace, String dateBirth) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.Birthplace = Birthplace;
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public String getPlace() {
        return Birthplace;
    }
    public String getDateBirth() {
        return dateBirth;
    }

    public void setDateBirth(String dateBirth) {
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd ',' MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        List<Persons> details = new ArrayList<Persons>();
        String text = "John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
        String[] personsSplit = text.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < personsSplit.length; i++) {
            String[]  personList = personsSplit[i].split("/");
            String[] print = personList[0].split("\\.");
            Persons newPerson = new Persons(print[0], print[1],
                    personList[2],  personList[1]);
            details .add(newPerson);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <details .size(); i++) {
            String outputString = "Person " + i + ": "
                    + details .get(i).getName() + " "
                    + details .get(i).getLastName() + ", "
                    +formatter.format(parser.parse(details .get(i).getDateBirth())) + ", "
                    + details .get(i).getPlace() + ";";
            System.out.println(outputString);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You did it right for the first 3 variables, but then you decided to go for a static variable (which means it's shared between all instances of a Person). Just change the `dateBirth` declaration to:

```
public String dateBirth;
```

And in the constructor, instead of `Persons.dateBirth` make it like the other variables as well:

```
this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
```

Comment: but give me a error  here   formatter.format(parser.parse(dateBirth)) (non- static variable dateBirth cannot be referenced from a static context)